# How to create a child class with one less constructor parameter from the parent constructor in java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have a parent class called Perishable and its constructor looks like this:

```
    public Perishable(String name, int shelfLife,
        double price) {
    super(name);
    this.shelfLife = shelfLife;
    this.price = price;
}
```

In this parent class, I need the shelfLife variable for other child classes. I have a particular child class though called LongShelfLife where the shelf life is always 720 days no matter what. Because of this, I've been instructed to have the class constructor only take two parameters, the name and the price (this is an assignment so I have to do it that way).

I came up with this code:

```
    public LongShelfLife(String name, double price) {
    name = super.name;
    price = super.price;
    }
```

But was told by the compiler that "Implicit super constructor Perishable() is undefined. Must explicitly evoke another constructor." I feel there must be a way to have only one constructor that only takes specific parameters from the parent constructor, for both the ease of it, and because I'm required to be able to do this. The only problem being that I have no idea how. If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class LongShelfLife extends Perishable {
    public LongShelfLife(String name, double price) {
        super(name, 720, price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LongShelfLife extends Perishable {
    public LongShelfLife(String name, double price) {
        super(name, 720, price);           // you know beforehand the value of shelf life so use it to call super constructor explicitly
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
    }
}
```